# Problems with pdfkit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdfkit

I am trying to generate pdfs on my website.

I was doing this for some time using 'wicked_pdf', but after a server update where I work it had some problems (The error message contained something along the lines of "Authentication error" and "try ignore load errors to fix"(but that didn't work)).

After a couple of days of trying to get it to work I gave up on it and I am currently trying to use the gem 'pdfkit' although using it, I get this error:

```
command failed (exitstatus=0): /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@nqspo-project8 /bin/wkhtmltopdf --quiet --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 --print-media-type - -
```

Any ideas why this is caused?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Try replacing "some problems" with details and then we should be able to help you out!

Comment: Well I don't know what was wrong with the 'wicked_pdf' gem, nor did anyone else
Now I am trying to use 'pdfkit' and I get the error I have in the OP.
What other details should I add to help you help me? ^^

Comment: Problems don't pop up from thin air. Something changed and caused the problems, either your code, server update or gem update. You should try and debug problem undoing changes and only then post questions to SO, giving all possible information. This post doesn't give any information to be honest.

Comment: Have you tried running the command yourself?
i.e. /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@nqspo-project8 /bin/wkhtmltopdf --quiet --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 --print-media-type

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel There was a server update(as I said in the OP), but I have no access to any of that or what happens to the server and the ones responsible for it have no idea why 'wicked_pdf' broke.

Comment: Something to be mindful of when using PDFkit and wkhtmltopdf  in general is that you need a server that spins up multiple threads. So you'll need something like unicorn. Essentially the RoR page requests wkhtmltopdf to generate the PDF and then that puts a request on the same server but that will hang because the server is waiting for wkhtmltopdf and thus you get a catch 22.

Comment: @KevinMonk Running the command returns this:
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@nqspo-project8: Is a directory

Comment: Yes. It will be. It's a gemset. But does this file even exist?
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@nqspo-project8/bin/wkhtmltopdf
There's a space between the gem directory and the binary for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

RE: Authentication.
Remember that wkhtmltopdf has a different session to **you** as an end user. For example, you may be logged in to the website, press the "Download as PDF" button, this spins up wkhtmltopdf and it tries to access the website as if it were a human visitor. It uses the webkit browser to access the website and then will extract the html and convert it to a PDF. The problem is that **wkhtmltopdf isn't logged in**. So whatever page you're sending it to you'll need to check that you've authorised wkhtmltopdf access to it.

Think of wkhtmltopdf as an additional visitor to your website. Typically you would append a One Time Password such as an auth_token in Devise that effectively logs in wkhtmltopdf as it's accessing it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I add authentication for when the pdf is requested? Sorry if this is a silly question, but I am kind of new to ruby on rails and most things are not clear for me/I don't know yet.

Comment: You would add an auth_token as a param in the URL.
Looks like it has changed quite recently though according to this...
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example
But essentially you add a OTP to the URL /dfssdf.html?auth_token=myamazingtoken